# Website is responsive on Google Chrome app but, not on Web View App of same Android device

Tags: java, android, webview, responsive-design, android-webview

I've generated apk for a website. The website when visited via url is fully responsive on different mobile devices such as Iphone 6s, Huawei P8 Lite, Samsung S4. Tested on different mobile browser namely, Google Chrome, Firefox. However, when I generate an apk basically a web view app of the website. It seems like some part of the website is not responsive on the same devices!

My App has the following code:

**dimens.xml**

```
<resources>
<dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">2dp</dimen>
<dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">2dp</dimen>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipe"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/web_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
swiper.setRefreshing(true);
    myWebView.loadUrl("<website_url>");
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

***Screen shot of website on Google Chrome App:***
[image: Google Chrome App]
***Screen shot of website on Webview App:***
[image: Web View App]

Comment: I see a difference on Chrome you have the tab where you can enter the URL in the Android Webview you have different screen size because you don't have a top tap.

Comment: Well, if we scroll that address bar disappears.

Comment: Did you used this `em` to declare heights?

Comment: No, I used `em` only on font-size e.g. `font-size: 1.3em;`

Comment: The website is responsive in both Firefox's and Google Chrome's [Device Toolbars](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/emulate-mobile-viewports).

Comment: Change `em` to something else because that doesn't work in Webview

Comment: Font size is not an issue here is it? The div height is not being responsive. Although all the media queries are on place. If you like you can check the website [here](http://172.104.49.183:8069/shop/)

Comment: Yeah I see it to position the box you used `position:absolute` and you also used `height 100% ` and `width 100%` on the body. Try to avoid `%` on the body. And use `flex-box` instead of `position` that will solve your problem. Remember not everthing that works in your browser will work on Android Webiew  

Link to flexbox : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/